# How can i get the dynamic value of button on click with id or data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI in this code only the first button on click event is working but when i click on 2nd nothin happen i don't want to use `input:button` coz i have multiple button on page..

```html
   <table border="1">
 <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>phone</td>
      <td>Btn</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>user 1</td>
      <td>user1@mail.com</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <button id="btnids" data-id="a1" value="a1">active</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>user 1</td>
      <td>user1@mail.com</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <button id="btnids" data-id="a2" value="a2">active</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>user 1</td>
      <td>user1@mail.com</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <button id="btnids" data-id="a3" value="a3">active</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#btnids").click(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
          });
    });
</script>
```

thanks!

Comment: `id`s should be unique. You need to use `class`

Comment: Don't use same id for every button. Use class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class instead of ID because element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

```html
<table border="1">
 <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>phone</td>
      <td>Btn</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>user 1</td>
      <td>user1@mail.com</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btnids" data-id="a1" value="a1">active</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>user 1</td>
      <td>user1@mail.com</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btnids" data-id="a2" value="a2">active</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>user 1</td>
      <td>user1@mail.com</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btnids" data-id="a3" value="a3">active</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".btnids").on('click',function(){
            alert($(this).val());
          });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Attribute `id` should be unique. Change the attribute from `id` to `class`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnids").click(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>phone</td>
    <td>Btn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>user 1</td>
    <td>user1@mail.com</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btnids" data-id="a1" value="a1">active</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>user 1</td>
    <td>user1@mail.com</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btnids" data-id="a2" value="a2">active</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>user 1</td>
    <td>user1@mail.com</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btnids" data-id="a3" value="a3">active</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```